# cannot implicitly convert type when groupby

Tags: c#, linq

I get this error when I try to group by `CellID`:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List
>   System.Linq.IGrouping int,p2pControllerLogAnalyser.Models.GSMData' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List
>   p2pControllerLogAnalyser.Models.GSMData'

```
public List<GSMData> GetCellID()
{
    return Gsmdata.GroupBy(x => x.CellID).ToList();
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: `GroupBy` returns an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>`, so it cannot be translated to `List<TElement>` in the manner you are doing. Why are you grouping at all? Why not `OrderBy` instead? Grouping and then immediately trying to flatten a list is either a) unintended or b) mimicking ordering semantics.

Comment: what expected output?

Comment: I want to show a list of CellID and how many Meters are using each CellID. The Grouping part is becouse there are multiple entries with the same CellID and i dont want duplicates

Comment: @user3240428 So you want distinct cell IDs?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you really need to do this, though I can't imagine why, you'll need to flatten the per-group enumerables into a single list using `SelectMany`:

```
public List<GSMData> GetCellID()
{
    return Gsmdata
        .GroupBy(x => x.CellID)
        .SelectMany(gr => gr)
        .ToList();
}
```

Of course, this looks like you are trying to batch items with the same `CellID` together, so you could always simply order it:

```
public List<GSMData> GetCellID()
{
    return Gsmdata
        .OrderBy(x => x.CellID)
        .ToList();
}
```

---

Further to your comments, distinct `CellID` values can be returned thus:

```
return Gsmdata.Select(x => x.CellID).Distinct();
```

If you wish to return an ID and a count of grouped data, you can bundle that into an anonymous type:

```
return Gsmdata
    .GroupBy(x => x.CellID)
    .Select(gr => new { CellID = gr.Key, Count = gr.Count() });
```

Though if you are returning this from a method I'd make a discoverable type and not use an anonymous type.

Answer (score 1):

if i understand right you need something like this

```
var result = (from gdata in Gsmdata
              group gdata by gbata.CellID into g
              select new Result{
                  CellID = g.Key,
                  Meters = g.Sum(i=>i.Meter)
              }
             ).ToList();
```

where `Result` is

```
public class Result{
    public /*type your CellID */ CellID;
    public /*type your Meter */  Meters;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that GroupBy returns a grouped collection, in this case `System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Linq.IGrouping<int, p2pControllerLogAnalyser.Models.GSMData>>`. Your method returns a `List<GSMData>`.

In order to fix this, you need to adjust your method declaration and/or your Linq query so that the types match.

From your comments, I understand that you want to return a list of the distinct cell ids. You can do this by changing both the method declaration and the Linq query (I'm assuming that CellID is of type `int` based upon the type in the IGrouping):

```
public List<int> GetCellID()
{
    return Gsmdata.Select(x => x.CellID)
                  .Distinct().ToList();
}
```